# Google's Speech-to-text streaming API not working in Electron-Vue

Tags: node.js, vue.js, google-api, electron

Since this is my first question here, I'll happily get tips on how to better ask a question.

I'm currently developing an application in Electron-Vue and we want to add the Google Speech-To-Text stream. I can make it work for an audiofile, but not the stream from the mic. These are the steps to take to reproduce my problem.

```
npm install -g vue-cli
vue init simulatedgreg/electron-vue my-project
```

Setup GCP console project and get credentials as described here:
https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/quickstart-client-libraries

Install and initialize Cloud SDK as described here:
https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/

Install SoX and add it to the PATH variable
https://sourceforge.net/projects/sox/files/latest/download

Install GRPC specifically for the targeted electron version. Simulatedgreg uses 2.0.14:

```
npm install --runtime=electron --target=2.0.14 --disturl=https://atom.io/download/electron
```

Install google cloud speech and node-record-lpcm-16

```
npm install @google-cloud/speech
npm install node-record-lpcm16
```

Now, for anyone not able to make the Google Speech to Text api working on NodeJS, this step is important. Go to node_modules and look up node-record-lpcm16 and open the index.js. Change the cmdArgs to this:

```
var cmd = 'sox';
var cmdArgs = [
'-q',                                     // show no progress
'-t', 'waveaudio',                        // input-type
'-d',                                     // use default recording device
'-r', options.sampleRate.toString(),      // sample rate
'-c', '1',                                // channels
'-e', 'signed-integer',                   // sample encoding
'-b', '16',                               // precision (bits)
'-t', 'raw',                              // output-type
'-'                                       // pipe
];
```

Place the credentials.json file that you generated from the API in project folder.

And finally the code voor Vue itself:

```
<template>
  <div id="wrapper">
          <button @click="record">Test</button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    name: 'landing-page',
    methods: {
      record(){
          this.version = process.versions.electron;
          const record = require('node-record-lpcm16');

// Imports the Google Cloud client library
          const speech = require('@google-cloud/speech');

// Creates a client
          const client = new speech.SpeechClient({
              keyFilename: './credentials.json'
          });

          const encoding = 'LINEAR16';
          const sampleRateHertz = 16000;
          const languageCode = 'nl-NL';

          const request = {
              config: {
                  encoding: encoding,
                  sampleRateHertz: sampleRateHertz,
                  languageCode: languageCode,
              },
              interimResults: false, // If you want interim results, set this to true
          };

// Create a recognize stream
          const recognizeStream = client
              .streamingRecognize(request)
              .on('error', console.error)
              .on('data', data =>
                  process.stdout.write(
                      data.results[0] && data.results[0].alternatives[0]
                          ? `Transcription: ${data.results[0].alternatives[0].transcript}\n`
                          : `\n\nReached transcription time limit, press Ctrl+C\n`
                  )
              );

// Start recording and send the microphone input to the Speech API
          record
              .start({
                  sampleRateHertz: sampleRateHertz,
                  threshold: 0,
                  // Other options, see https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-record-lpcm16#options
                  verbose: false,
                  recordProgram: 'sox', // Try also "arecord" or "sox"
                  silence: '10.0',
              })
              .on('error', console.error)
              .pipe(recognizeStream);

          console.log('Listening, press Ctrl+C to stop.');
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

I do realize that since I made it work in NodeJS itself, I could use a seperate NodeJS server bundled with the electron application and communicate over a websocket, but I want to keep it as simple as possible for the enduser. Thanks in advance.